# default to computed value for security group not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have this in my module:

```
variable vpc_security_group_ids {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
```

If the user doesnt specify it I want it to default to the computed group (which is "default").

This work the first time but the second time I apply I see this:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ module.servers.aws_instance.aws-inst[0]
      vpc_security_group_ids.#:          "1" => "0"
      vpc_security_group_ids.2662974173: "sg-123abc" => ""
```

Its trying to set it back to "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing default = [] in your code. So if you don't pass any security group then AWS creates an instance with default vpc security group and it will be saved in terraform state file. But, when you will try next time with default = [] then it will show that instance already have one security group and you are trying to remove it (during plan phase), but during apply, either it(apply) will fail or it will not remove the security group.

So ideally you should create a security group and then use it as default. like

```
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
    type = "list"
    default = [<default_security_group_id>]
}
```